# Mirror without deleting or adding new material

Tags: mesh, mirror

I modified and existing rig and I want the left side to mirror the changes I did on the right side. Is there a way to do this without deleting half the character?

Comment: Did you modify the rig or the mesh or both?

Answer (score 4):

I assume you mean that you edited the Rig. In that case you can do this:

- In the tool shelf: Vertical Options Tab enable X-Mirror
- In your Armature, in Edit Mode: select all bones which you have modified (similar like in the image)
- press "g" followed by RETURN will instantly adjust the other side of your rig.

**Note:** This works only if the Rig's symmetry plane is YZ (character looks along Y axis) and when the Bones are named according to Blender's naming conventions, see http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Rigging/Armatures/Editing/Properties

[image: Selected part is the modified side]

Comment: I added a comment about how I just modified only the vertices 6-8 hours ago? Sorry.

Comment: I do not see that comment that you made 6-8 hours ago. I have no elegant solution for mirroring one side of the mesh to the other side except using a mirror modifier, or possibly Mesh -> Symmetrize  (in edit mode). Actually x-mirror is also available for meshes, but it sometimes fails (depending on the mesh topology)

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest you are going to get is *Mesh > Snap to symmetry*:

[image]

It works by snapping the nearest vertices to a mirrored position, however this won't always work perfectly if you have larger changes. It probably won't work at all if you have a lot of asymmetric topology.

If you have yet to make the changes (or you can make them again), you could try *X mirror*:

[image]